# Show a entire function $f$ is constant if $f(\mathbb{C}) \cap \{\mathbb{R}^+\} = \emptyset$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show a entire function $f$ is constant if $f(\mathbb{C}) \cap \{\mathbb{R}^+\} = \emptyset$ where $\mathbb{R^+} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x>0\}$.

I want to apply Liouville theorem but having difficulties showing how $f$ is bounded. Noticing non-constant $f$ is open and has dense image might help.

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is not constant we also have $0\notin f(\Bbb C)$, so there is a square root $g$ of $f$, what values can $g$ attain?

Comment: Alternatively note that there is a biholomorphic map $\Bbb C\setminus\{x\in \Bbb R\mid x\geq 0\}\to\Bbb D=\{z\in\Bbb C\mid |z|<1\}$ and then use Liouville

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Assume $f$ nonconstant. Then $f(\mathbb{C})$ is open, and so  the image of $g\colon =-f$ is contained in $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty, 0]$, and $h=\sqrt{g}$ has image in $\{ z = x + i y \ | x > 0\}$, $u = \frac{h-1}{h+1}$ has image in the unit disk, so constant.